# Sub-Referencing an Array in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, type-conversion

I'm developing a simple processor emulator, and one of my specs says that all registers must be sub-accessible down to the bytes (It's a 32-bit processor, so there are 4 byte registers for every normal register). When I need to access a register, I need some way to figure out whether I'm going to be getting a uchar, ushort, uint or float based on its ID. I know ahead of time which registers point to which type, but there's no way I know of storing the register pointers that will allow me to, disregarding the return types, perform arbitrary arithmetic with those values. I thought maybe C++11 could help me out here, but I don't know where to look.

I've considered typecasting the pointers in a switch statement, but I'd have to redo that switch statement in the function actually asking for the values, because a function can't change return type mid-execution.

I've considered using templated objects to point out the registers, but I can't store templated objects with different template parameters in the same array (or can I?)

Comment: You might want to read about [unions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)?

Comment: Even if I used unions, the function requesting the value would have to choose the type. That's basically the same as the pointer-casting option. Although...I could have pointers to the union's members...and then I'd have to cast the pointers, again.

Comment: Each register could be stored as a structure containing the type and the value union. Or you can do something more like real processors does it and don't really care about the type, a register is just a storage place of up to 32 bits. Then you treat that data differently depending on instruction (floating-point instructions uses the data as a floating-point value, integer arithmetic can have two bits to say what size the data is, etc.).

Comment: I need to clarify. Instructions don't choose the types they operate on. The registers do. If you do ADD with a uint register and a uchar register, it should add those just fine, and store them in whichever register is the target, without spilling the overflow onto other parts of the register. EDIT: The reason for this is that I have a severely limited number of instructions, and a large number of registers.

Comment: Your unions proposal makes it so that storing results will fix overflow problems. I just wish I didn't have to do so much casting (but at this point it seems unavoidable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's no easy way to solve this. However, I was able to store the types of the array elements in a parallel array of integers. I would ask for the type, and use a switch statement to cast to the necessary types and perform calculations. The source can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/uberblah/emu/tree/master).

Answer (score 0):

Generally `union`s are... tricky and you should avoid them . But in a case of a CPU-emulator I would argue, since registers are exactly acting as `unions` are designed, this might be one of the rare cases you can/should use them.

`unions` opens the door to a lot of type-unsafety. But since your CPU will also just execute the instructions on the registers in a non-typesafe manner (presumably), just make a register a union. They are quite not-C++11, but pure C (only tiny additions in C++11).

```
union Register {
    uint32_t val;
    struct {
        uint16_t lo;
        uint16_t hi;
    } u16;
    struct {
        uint8_t b0;
        uint8_t b1;
        uint8_t b2;
        uint8_t b3;
    } u8;
 };
```

Or similar.

Of course you *could* implement a type-checking CPU, or a simulator that executes only type-safe code, but I guess that is beyond the  scope of your task.